# LinQ to SQL missing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get all rows from my `SANPHAM` table but somehow it keeps missing some rows. The table has 9 rows, however, when displayed, it show only 5 rows (I have picture below, and don't mind about products' image, I will add the rests later).

I have tried to do something in my code, I change `int i = 0` to `int i = 1` and there are 2 situations. With i = 0, the result misses even rows and with i = 1, odd rows disappear.

I am a newbie to this, I looked for some solutions but still can't fix it, hope you guys can help

Here is my code:

HomeControllers.cs:

```
namespace MvcApplication.Controllers
{ 
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {        
        private LinQtoSQLDataContext LinQtoSQLDataContext = new LinQtoSQLDataContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IList<Models.SanPhamModels> sanPhamList = new List<Models.SanPhamModels>();
            var query = from sanpham in LinQtoSQLDataContext.SANPHAMs select sanpham;
            var sps = query.ToList();

            foreach (var sanPhamData in sps)
            {
                sanPhamList.Add(new Models.SanPhamModels()
                {
                    maSanPham = sanPhamData.maSanPham,
                    tenSanPham = sanPhamData.tenSanPham,
                    gia = sanPhamData.gia,
                    tacGia = sanPhamData.tacGia,
                    moTa = sanPhamData.moTa,
                    maDanhMuc = sanPhamData.maDanhMuc,
                    hinhAnh = sanPhamData.hinhAnh
                });
            }
            return View(sanPhamList);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@for (int i=0; i<Model.Count; i++)
{
    var tmp = "<div class=\"product_box\">";
    tmp += "<a href=\"" + Url.Action("Index", "productdetail", new { maSanPham = Model[i].maSanPham }) + "\"><img src=\""+ Url.Content(Model[i].hinhAnh) + "\" alt=\"Image\" /></a><br>";
    tmp += Html.ActionLink(Model[i].tenSanPham, "productdetail", new { maSanPham = Model[i].maSanPham }, null);
    tmp += "<p class=\'product_price\">" + Model[i].gia.ToString() + "</p>";
    tmp += Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "shoppingcart", new { maSanPham = Model[i].maSanPham }, new {@class = "add_to_card"});
    tmp += Html.ActionLink("Detail", "productdetail", new { maSanPham = Model[i].maSanPham }, new { @class = "detail" });
    tmp += "</div>";

    @Html.Raw(tmp)        
}
```

SanPhamModels:

```
namespace MvcApplication.Models
{
    public class SanPhamModels
    {
        public string maSanPham { get; set; }
        public string tenSanPham { get; set; }
        public double gia { get; set; }
        public string tacGia { get; set; }
        public string moTa { get; set; }
        public string maDanhMuc { get; set; }
        public string hinhAnh { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzYJL.png)

[My website result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfY4j.png)

### EDITED:

I see what problem with my project: 
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNhjC.png)
a `<div>` inside a `<div>` so that it shows only the odd rows or even rows. Now I am working on this issue, still need some help...

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the model in top with list as you are returning the list from controller.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.SanPhamModels>
```

Comment: you mean in index.cshtml? sr, I forgot to copy the line in my file: "@model List<MvcApplication.Models.SanPhamModels>". However, I've tried your solution, it still not working, cause when I changed List to IEnumerable, I was not able to use Model.Count().

Comment: try with Model.Count

Comment: Thank you. But I edited my post, something happened with the loop which generates a <div> inside <p>. I tried foreach but still not have any hopes :(